# vignette() function unable to find vignettes in R

Tags: r, package, vignette

I've been working on a package. At first, I would build vignettes with regularity, and the vignette() function would be able to find them. But then something broke and I have no clue what it is, and vignette() doesn't work even with default code.

I create a brand new package 'tabtest', which automatically creates a function 'hello', and I do:

```
usethis::use_vignette("my-vignette")
```

To create the vignette file, of which I change nothing and save.

Then, I use Ctrl-Shift-B to build, and do

```
library(tabtest)
vignette(hello)
```

And get the error 'Error in topic[1L] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable' which is the same error I'm getting in my actual package.

Notably, if I do

```
devtools::build_vignettes()
```

It runs no problem and creates accurate vignette files in the doc/ folder, but vignette() cannot find them. Also, if I upload the code to github and use install_github, it can't find vignettes then either.

I must have flipped some weird switch somewhere. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a string to `vignette` like this:

```
vignette("hello")
```